# Is it valid for a hyperlink tag to have multiple images?

Tags: html

```
<a href="#"><img src="#"/>Hello World<img src="#"/><img src="#"/></a>
```

Is this Html valid? (Assuming I replace the hash characters with proper links.)

Comment: yes it is: just evaluate if your images are part of the content or part of the style; and consider the correct use of the `alt` attribute for the images

Comment: Wouldn't running it through a validator tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is valid. You can have as much text and images as you would like in a hyperlink.